# This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php

This error occured when i am trying to access my admin panel of website on localhost server here is the code of my admin panel index.php

```
 <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$http_header = 'http://';
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $http_header = 'https://';
}
$this_url   = $http_header . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$this_url = str_replace('admin-panel', 'admin-cp', $this_url);
header("Location: $this_url");
exit();
?>
You can access the admin panel, from <a href="<?php echo $this_url ?>"><?php echo $this_url ?></a>
```

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)! Did you take a look at the logs to figure out what went wrong?

Comment: Please always post code, not an image of code. From your screenshot I cannot tell if there is a space on line 12 after the first `$`

Comment: Yes i have check the logs but there is no error

Comment: there is now space after $

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: still not showing me any error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score -1):

Try testing for `admin-panel` in the URL before redirecting, like this:

```
if (strpos($this_url, 'admin-panel') !== false)
{
    $this_url = str_replace('admin-panel', 'admin-cp', $this_url);
    header("Location: $this_url");
    exit();
}
```

If `str_replace('admin-panel', 'admin-cp', $this_url)` fails, `$this_url` remains unchanged. If `header` redirects to the same page you will get an error like *"unable to handle request 500 clear your cookies"*, or something similar.